# how to add non .py files into python egg

Tags: python, deployment, setup.py

I have a flask app which looks like

```
my-app 
│   └── src
│       └── python
│             └── config
│             └── app
│── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.py
```

The config folder is full of *.yaml files, I want to add all the static config files into my python egg after using

```
python setup.py install
```

My setup.py looks like

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
setup(
    name="app",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Anna",
    description="",
    keywords=[],
    packages=find_packages(path + '/src/python'),
    package_dir={'': path + '/src/python'},
    include_package_data=True
)
```

I am trying the use the MANIFEST.in to add the config file
However, it always give error

```
error: Error: setup script specifies an absolute path:

/Users/Anna/Desktop/my-app/src/python/app

setup() arguments must *always* be /-separated paths relative to the
setup.py directory, *never* absolute paths.
```

I have not used any absolute paths in my code, I've seen other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085571/pip-install-error-setup-script-specifies-an-absolute-path) trying to bypass this error, by removing

```
include_package_data=True
```

However, in my case, if i do this to avoid this error, all my yamls won't be added.

I was wondering if there are ways to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: You *have* used absolute paths, what did you think abspath meant?

Comment: oh ops.. i thought path is 'relative' so this is a relative path. thanks for pointing that out!